# BitGO-JS Exceed Transaction 250 limit

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, while-loop, promise

I'm trying simulate with the help of test.bitgo.com more than 250 transactions which is the current limit set for the API... I tried and tried again different methods to achieve the same results and after one week I still can't find a proper way get all the transaction data in one GO .

One of their devs said that I could do it with a Promise that has a nested while-loop that adds the count:250 to skip:0 and run the function again and again until there is nothing left to sum up because count gets to 0 at the end and gets all 852 transactions.

This is what i'm using https://www.bitgo.com/api/#list-wallet-transactions. It gives back an object that has 250 transactions and keeps count like this.

```
var walletId = '2NB96fbwy8eoHttuZTtbwvvhEYrBwz494ov';
bitgo.wallets().get({ "id": walletId }, function callback(err, wallet) {
  if (err) { throw err; }
wallet.transactions({limit:2, skip:0}, function callback(err, transactions) {
// handle transactions
console.log(JSON.stringify(transactions, null, 4));
  });
});

// This is the result

{
"transactions": [
    {
        "id": "71fb53e7d70ce27dced2eb327ac544b8f046e66480342ba81533046f3267e6f4",
        "normalizedHash": "80116b194b58b494d85b2a831815a978ec6f0fe617cfd020880ff1ad76b2bacc",
        "date": "2016-04-17T20:06:56.474Z",
        "fee": 4480,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "previousHash": "1f4145b615f5d067160184a3e9660396f826614c3fcae9abdcb7192c615b843a",
                "previousOutputIndex": 0
            }
        ],
        "outputs": [
            {
                "vout": 0,
                "account": "2N5Jr87jhTuAHab37VKWNPhoH1WUEHkVg1Q",
                "value": 625000000,
                "isMine": true,
                "chain": 0,
                "chainIndex": 0
            },
            {
                "vout": 1,
                "account": "mpntSJWk116JF58VRDxeMMwr4gC7afVEKt",
                "value": 390110612
            }
        ],
        "entries": [
            {
                "account": "2N5Jr87jhTuAHab37VKWNPhoH1WUEHkVg1Q",
                "value": 625000000
            },
            {
                "account": "mqRsJr8szT5XTSLm3CU7i9ePa7kWnC2VWs",
                "value": -1015115092
            },
            {
                "account": "mpntSJWk116JF58VRDxeMMwr4gC7afVEKt",
                "value": 390110612
            }
        ],
        "confirmations": 487,
        "pending": false,
        "instant": false,
        "blockhash": "000000000000020f526fe18af7536fa4e816694c4dec865e0d87d6b722b643d9",
        "height": 786821
    },
    {
        "id": "e5216ffaaa2a37bcc14380db07f06c85a65bcdc4e1fcab2bd5523f0b8a11bc15",
        "normalizedHash": "0709c99097386a3c0130f3d6b002acf6a4e37978406704268fc9d308eec4c2b8",
        "date": "2016-04-17T20:07:03.700Z",
        "fee": 7440,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "previousHash": "6d043a06ade4eac5315967c463fcd65deb4ed9bff23ee3e73ff82c9cf72360e9",
                "previousOutputIndex": 1
            },
            {
                "previousHash": "b6e566cbee0f23bee7b321eda7f6159a165101e77e7f1e75bd9eb6e31540b391",
                "previousOutputIndex": 0
            }
        ],
        "outputs": [
            {
                "vout": 0,
                "account": "2N5Jr87jhTuAHab37VKWNPhoH1WUEHkVg1Q",
                "value": 312500000,
                "isMine": true,
                "chain": 0,
                "chainIndex": 0
            },
            {
                "vout": 1,
                "account": "mmRuajWq2xPYQw4gjXz8pQ2fUfJTF7fvYe",
                "value": 3831779
            }
        ],
        "entries": [
            {
                "account": "2N5Jr87jhTuAHab37VKWNPhoH1WUEHkVg1Q",
                "value": 312500000
            },
            {
                "account": "muEePZzkRWX3RnLWHxTx6r8T3MMruTgMgg",
                "value": -312084680
            },
            {
                "account": "mmRuajWq2xPYQw4gjXz8pQ2fUfJTF7fvYe",
                "value": 3831779
            },
            {
                "account": "n47gD5D3XfBG41tWKX4YHNc9gboyWU9yJg",
                "value": -4254539
            }
        ],
        "confirmations": 487,
        "pending": false,
        "instant": false,
        "blockhash": "000000000000020f526fe18af7536fa4e816694c4dec865e0d87d6b722b643d9",
        "height": 786821
    }
],
"start": 0,
"count": 2,
"total": 852
}
```

As you can see i have a total of "total":852 transactions, the skip parameter is equal to "start":0 and the limit is equal to "count":2

LEGEND:
limit:250 will only display 250 transactions from a total of 852
skip:250 will skip the first 250 transactions and start to display 251 >= 500

The main problem is I can only get a maximum of 250 transactions at a time and i tried to push the results to an array and concatenate everything with the help of lodash but failed. Tried to make it work by having tons of requests that skip:250 then 500 then 750 etc and still failed cleaning and saving everything.

Hope someone already had to climb this hill and is willing to spend a few minutes to point me in the right direction. Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a recursive asynchronous function that repeatedly calls wallet.transactions({skip: skip}) with larger and larger values for "skip", which will allow you to traverse through all the transactions on the wallet. Take a look at the code below:

```
var BitGoJS = require('bitgo');

var user = 'octavian@l.com';
var loginPassword = 'supersecretpassword';
var otp = '0000000';
var walletId = 'yourWalletId';

var bitgo = new BitGoJS.BitGo();


var printTxs = function() {
  // Now get the wallet
  bitgo.wallets().get({ id: walletId }, function(err, wallet) {
    if (err) { console.log("Error getting wallet!"); console.dir(err); return process.exit(-1); }

    var allTxs = [];

    /**
     * Fetch transactions from the wallet using skip as an index into the array of all
     * transactions on the wallet
     * @param skip {Number} the number of transactions we should skip ahead
     */
    var getTransactionBatch = function(skip, callback) {
      wallet.transactions({ skip: skip }, function(err, res) {
        if (err) { console.log("Error getting transactions!"); console.dir(err); return process.exit(-1); }

        res.transactions.forEach(function(tx) {
          allTxs.push(tx);
        });

        var totalTxCount = res.total;

        if (totalTxCount && totalTxCount > allTxs.length) {
          var newSkip = skip + res.count; // add the number of tx's we just fetched to the number we already skipped ahead

          return getTransactionBatch(newSkip, callback);
        }

        return callback();
      });
    };

    getTransactionBatch(0, function() {
      console.log('All Transactions\n');
      console.log(JSON.stringify(allTxs, null, 2));
    })
  });
};

// Authenticate first
bitgo.authenticate({ username: user, password: loginPassword, otp: otp }, function(err, result) {
  if (err) { console.dir(err); throw new Error("Could not authenticate!"); }
  console.log("Unlocking account.." );
  bitgo.unlock({ otp: otp }, function(err) {
    if (err) { console.dir(err); throw new Error("Could not unlock!"); }
    printTxs();
  });
});
```

Once you fill in the login credentials and walletId at the top with the appropriate values, this function will make repeated calls to BitGo and each time add the transactions it receives in the response to the `allTxs` array. Once that array is equal in size to the total number of tx's on the wallet, it will print out all the transactions. Replace the console.log call with whatever processing you want to do on the transactions, and you'll be golden!

Comment: Thank you **almel** , your code is fascinating:) . Had this issue for more than a week and was literally going insane... Thank you so so much for saving the day !